# How to filter a select nodeset with a PHP function?

Tags: php, xslt

I wonder if and how it is possible to register a PHP userspace function with the XSLT processor that is able not only to take an array of nodes but also to return it?

Right now PHP complains about an array to string conversion using the common setup:

```
function all_but_first(array $nodes) {        
    array_shift($nodes);
    shuffle($nodes);
    return $nodes;
};

$proc = new XSLTProcessor();
$proc->registerPHPFunctions();
$proc->importStylesheet($xslDoc);
$buffer = $proc->transformToXML($xmlDoc);
```

The XMLDocument (`$xmlDoc`) to transform can for example be:

```
<p>
   <name>Name-1</name>
   <name>Name-2</name>
   <name>Name-3</name>
   <name>Name-4</name>
</p>
```

Within the stylesheet it's called like this:

```
<xsl:template name="listing">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="php:function('all_but_first', /p/name)">
    </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>
```

The notice is the following:

> Notice: Array to string conversion

I don't understand why if the function gets an array as input is not able to return an array as well?

I was also trying other "function" names as I've seen there is `php:functionString` but all  tried so far (`php:functionArray`, `php:functionSet` and `php:functionList`) did not work.

In the PHP manual it's written I can return another `DOMDocument` containing elements, however then those elements aren't from the original document any longer. That does not make much sense to me.

Comment: I did a longer research on this, and I came up with the same solution as stated in the last sentence: You'd need to return another `DOMDocument` from this function. But then it gets bugly again, because I just got out the plain text and no nodes. (`xsl:for-each` didn't help either)

Comment: @DanLee: Thanks for the feedback. Just tried with an iterator but it's no joy, too: *"Warning: A PHP Object cannot be converted to a XPath-string"* - then [I've taken a look into source](http://lxr.sweon.net/php/http/source/ext/dom/xpath.c#L222) and it only handles object that are an instance of some DomNode - so getting all node's xpaths, union them and returning the "real" DomNodeList didn't work either. It's a mess :) It's probably worth to suggest allowing an array of dom nodes here as a return value.

Comment: I linked the wrong library, but the code is identical: http://lxr.sweon.net/php/http/source/ext/xsl/xsltprocessor.c#L331

Comment: Yes indeed it's a mess and I think your suggestion should be added. Maybe you should file a bug report. By the way I was working with the help of this php.net comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/xsltprocessor.registerphpfunctions.php#59280

Comment: +1 to bring out this. Can you provide more details about your function `all_but_first` with example array, your sample xml, xsl? I am interested in this question and have executed a basic example from php.net. I would like to go in depth with this concept because might be I will have this type of requirement in future. Your sample (xml, xsl and value of array in function) data would be helpful to me to go further on this topic.

Comment: @NullVoid: Doesn't the example from the question illustrate it well enough? AFAIK only some XML is missing but you can there pretty much everytinng from where you can retrieve a nodelist with the xpath. Just let me know.

Comment: Yes. I have created my own AFAIK XML from php.net example. But wanted to if you have one of your test sample and xpath in form of array then I could test it at my end. This will make process fast :)

Comment: Let me check I might have this on disk.

Comment: Yes. Sure. Will be waiting for your sample XML and XPath snippet

Comment: Okay, I could not dig that up in a useful. I wanted to use that in some project where the actual XML is multiple megabyte large when processed. Ut's easier to add just a simple XML chunk here fitting the xpath. **Edit:** https://gist.github.com/hakre/5584499

Comment: I think the reason is this: You return an array of Nodes (as most Xpath functions in PHP return) but your XSL Transformation needs a node with child nodes. So Array versus Node.

Comment: Another small note: If it complains that it needs a String, did you try to return a String containing XML? Maybe it needs an XML as String as a result. DomDocument is probably auto converted to string... (Just a guess)

Comment: @ToBe: This question is most likely a feature request, yes. It's an open anchor to leave an answer when this works or a feasible work-around is provided.

Comment: As I had understood thing you are trying to do is like extending xsl? and I want to tell you my English is not so good.(X

Comment: @imsiso: Yes, I'd like to better integrate with XSL here.

Comment: As I'm getting the point. I need to have a study on it but I just suggest (as you know ) `DOMDocument` for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something that works for me is to return an instance of [`DOMDocumentFragment`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocumentfragment.php) instead of an array.  So to try it on your example, I saved your input as `foo.xml`.  Then I made `foo.xslt` look like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'
        xmlns:php="http://php.net/xsl">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:call-template name="listing" />
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="name">
        <bar> <xsl:value-of select="text()" /> </bar>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="listing">
        <foo>
            <xsl:for-each select="php:function('all_but_first', /p/name)">
                <xsl:apply-templates />
            </xsl:for-each>
        </foo>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

(This is mostly just your example with a `xsl:stylesheet` wrapper to invoke it.)  And the real heart of the matter, `foo.php`:

```
<?php

function all_but_first($nodes) {
    if (($nodes == null) || (count($nodes) == 0)) {
        return ''; // Not sure what the right "nothing" return value is
    }
    $returnValue = $nodes[0]->ownerDocument->createDocumentFragment();
    array_shift($nodes);
    shuffle($nodes);
    foreach ($nodes as $node) {
        $returnValue->appendChild($node);
    }
    return $returnValue;
};

$xslDoc = new SimpleXMLElement('./foo.xslt', 0, true);
$xmlDoc = new SimpleXMLElement('./foo.xml', 0, true);

$proc = new XSLTProcessor();
$proc->registerPHPFunctions();
$proc->importStylesheet($xslDoc);
$buffer = $proc->transformToXML($xmlDoc);
echo $buffer;

?>
```

The important part being the call to `ownerDocument->createDocumentFragment()` to make the object that gets returned from the function.

Comment: I wasn't aware of your answer until right now. Thanks a lot, this really works  :) - Great!