# PHP registered functions in XSLT1, how to return a XML fragment with PHP?

Tags: php, xml, xslt-1.0

I am using [PHP with XSL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xsl.php) and [registerPHPfunctions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/xsltprocessor.registerphpfunctions.php).

It is ok for return PHP string values with `xsl:value-of`, but I not know how to return XML fragments from PHP.

---

Example at XSLT:

```
 <xsl:template match="table">
     <xsl:copy-of select="php:function('myfunc',.)"/>
 </xsl:template>
```

Example at PHP:

```
 function myfunc($x) {return '<table><tr><td>ok</td></tr></table>';}
```

Result is not XML but a "lt/gt/amp enconded XML". Use of `copy-of` or `value-of` at XSL, not modify the return behaviour. It is a cast problem?

PS: even with identity function, I tested, it not returns the XML node,

```
 function myfunc($x) {return $x;}
```

Comment: There is `<xsl:value-of select="php:function('myfunc') disable-output-escaping="yes" />` for that. But to use it is considered *bad practice* - and its not working with PHP :| ( I tested with 5.3.10 Ubuntu 12.04). I would advice you to create the `<xml>` nodes in the xsl not in the php functions. But however I don't know your application needs

Comment: Hum... I try `disable-output-escaping` on my PHP environment and, also, not working... How to submit  a "feature request" to PHP community?  PHP not have XSLT2 or xQuery, so it is very important to PHP-XML users... Well, for my application I need to return nodes (not only string-values).

Comment: You could try to work with `<xsl:if>` for example to create the xml tree in xsl depending on the return value of a php function

Comment: Here is an existing feature request: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=36156

Comment: Possible related: [How to filter a select nodeset with a PHP function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12960211/how-to-filter-a-select-nodeset-with-a-php-function)

Comment: For a complete **tutorial about registerPHPFunctions**, see https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/PHP_Programming/XSL/registerPHPFunctions

Answer (score 2):

Just return any subclass of `DOMNode`:

```php
$xml = '<root/>';
$xsl = <<<'EOL'
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
     xmlns:php="http://php.net/xsl">
    <xsl:template match="/root">
        <xsl:copy-of select="php:function('myXMLFunc', .)"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
EOL;

function myXMLFunc($m) { // $m is always an array of DOMNodes
    $d = new DOMDocument();
    $e = $d->createElement('newroot');
    $e->appendChild($d->createTextNode('inner text'));
    return $e;
}

$xmldoc = DOMDocument::loadXML($xml);
$xsldoc = DOMDocument::loadXML($xsl);

$proc = new XSLTProcessor();
$proc->registerPHPFunctions('myXMLFunc');
$proc->importStyleSheet($xsldoc);

echo $proc->transformToXML($xmldoc);
```

The above will produce the xml `<newroot>inner text</newroot>`.

You can also construct your xml with `SimpleXMLElement` and convert to a DOM tree with [`dom_import_simplexml()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dom-import-simplexml.php), which you can then return.  Using SimpleXML to construct xml is usually much less painful.

Comment: Thanks a lot (!), yor method is "more DOM-explicit". Now and I am studing and comparing (the simplest!) solutions... And I'm curious about identity function: how to return $m in your myXMLFunc($m) function? (and where you see good documentation or tutorials about all this subject?)

Comment: The argument to the php function is always an array (representing a nodeset). You can do `return $m[0]`. A generic identity function is not possible, since the return value must always be either a single `DOMNode` (or subclass) or something that can be coerced to a string. It does not seem possible to return a nodeset, or at least the obvious ways (`array` or `DOMNodeList`) don't work. You can emulate nodesets with a container element, but you must discard it on the XSLT side.

Comment: A note, this feature (exposing php methods to xslt) is poorly documented and poorly supported, and has much ugliness about it. Rely on it as little as possible.

Answer (score 0):

OPS, it is some kind of magic!  Now the @hek2mgi tip is working!

I am using

```
 <xsl:template match="table">
  <xsl:copy-of select="php:function('myfunc',.)" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
 </xsl:template>
```

...I will back here in some days to say something more about "stable solution" and conclusions...