# create NodeSet in XSLT from PHP function

Tags: php, xml, xslt

I want to create XML in an PHP function and return it to XSLT.
In XSLT i would like to create a node-set and use it.

In PHP i have a function which returns XML as a string.

```
function xmlString() {
    $string = ''.
        '<test>'.
            '<a>1</a>'.
            '<b>2</b>'.
        '</test>'.
        '<test>'.
            '<a>3</a>'.
        '</test>'.
    '';
    return $string;
}
```

i already registered this function in PHP and use it in XSLT

```
<xsl:variable name="xmlString">
    <xsl:value-of select="php:function('xmlString')" />
</xsl:variable>
```

to disable the output escaping i used `disable-output-escaping="yes"` on the value-of

i also played around with `exsl:node-set` but i can't get it work

i would like to use it like `<xsl:value-of select="exsl:node-set($xmlString)/test/b" />`

Comment: `exsl:node-set` takes a result tree fragment and converts it into a node-set. You have a string that happens to be XML and you want to parse it into a node-set. There is no such function in XSLT 1.0. You could try whether PHP allows you to do the parsing on the PHP side, meaning whether you can create a DOMDocument in your PHP code and pass that back to XSLT, perhaps then you can use it as a node-set on the XSLT side. But I have never tried that.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Yes, that works. I've done that.

Comment: @ThW: That's interesting! I asked that ages ago and didn't manage it, now I see it has been answered and it works: [How to filter a select nodeset with a PHP function?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12960211/367456).

Comment: @MartinHonnen could you please provide me an example? I tried to create xml with PHP `DOMDocument` and return that with `saveXML()` to xslt. But i can't get it work to create a node-set out of that which i can use in XSLT.

Comment: As I have said, I have never done that, I am currently not even on a machine set up to do PHP. But of course doing `saveXML` is wrong, you need to return the nodes so e.g. `function makeXml() { $doc = new DOMDocument(); $frag = $doc->createDocumentFragment(); $frag->appendXML('<test><a>foo</a></test>'); return $frag; }` in the PHP code and `<xsl:variable name="frag" select="php:function('makeXml')"/>` and `<xsl:apply-templates select="$frag/test/a"/>`in the PHP code. I hope someone of the PHP guys can help with a tested example.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example tested with PHP 5.5:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>PHP extension function returns DOM document fragment to XSLT to be treated as node-set in XSLT</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php

function makeXml() {
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $frag = $doc->createDocumentFragment();
    $frag->appendXML('<test><a>foo</a></test><test><a>bar</a></test>');
    return $frag;
}


$xml = <<<EOB
<root></root>
EOB;

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($xml);

$xsl = <<<'EOB'
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
     xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
     xmlns:php="http://php.net/xsl"
     exclude-result-prefixes="exsl php">

<xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:variable name="frag" select="php:function('makeXml')"/>

  <ul>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$frag/test/a"/>
  </ul>

 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="a">
   <li>
     <xsl:apply-templates/>
   </li>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
EOB;

$xsldoc = new DOMDocument();
$xsldoc->loadXML($xsl);

$proc = new XSLTProcessor();
$proc->registerPHPFunctions();

$proc->importStyleSheet($xsldoc);
echo $proc->transformToXML($doc);


?>

</body>
</html>
```

Output is

```
<html>                                                                                                                                
<head>                                                                                                                               
<title>PHP extension function returns DOM document fragment to XSLT to be treated as node-set in XSLT</title>                                                                                                                                
</head>                                                                                                                               
<body>                                                                                                                                
<ul>                                                                                                                                  
<li>foo</li>                                                                                                                          
<li>bar</li>                                                                                                                          
</ul>                                                                                                                                 
</body>                                                                          </html>
```