# XSLT 1.0 Loop Over Data Array

Tags: xslt

I've been plugging away at this XSLT stuff and I'm struggling with it.   I'm using a software that already creates the XSLT template and adds order object.  I've looped over that and everything is well, however I have a serialized object that I need to loop over.   I've got a custom PHP function processing this, so I have completely control over what the output looks like, but I just don't know how to loop over a variable.

This is what I have so far and I've tried several other combinations:

```
    <xsl:variable name="mi">
        <xsl:value-of select="php:functionString('Client\Marketing\Helper\Order::unserializeMarketingItems', increment_id)"/>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:for-each select="$mi">
        <xsl:value-of select="item_id" />

    </xsl:for-each>
```

Because I am calling the custom php function (unserializeMarketingData) I can and have tried making this an xml structure and even returned a regular object.

But what I can't seem to make happen is have this loop over the object with the for-each.   It just causes the script to go white or doesn't output anything at all.

So to summarize, how can I take a string of any type of data and loop over it in the XSLT template?   Or is this even the right approach?

Comment: The `xsl:for-each` instruction can only operate on objects of type *node-set*. You have a variable of type *result-tree-fragment*, containing a single *text* node. Show us the output of the php function and explain what you want to receive as the result of processing it.

Comment: Assuming that is PHP 5 or later and you want to return an XML document then return a `DOMDocument` or a `DOMDocumentFragment`.  But use `<xsl:variable name="mi" select="php:functionString('Client\Marketing\Helper\Order::unserializeMarketingItems', increment_id)"/>` at the XSLT side of code. As for processing nodes in the returned document or fragment, you would need at least `<xsl:for-each select="$mi//foo">` to process the `foo` elements in the XML.

Comment: This is what my return data looks like: <?xml version="1.0"?><?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" ?><marketing><items><item_id>1</item_id><qty>1</qty><product_id>116</product_id><product_name>Thanks for Shopping!</product_name><product_sku>91411</product_sku></items><items><item_id>2</item_id><qty>1</qty><product_id>117</product_id><product_name>Welcome to Concierge!</product_name><product_sku>91412</product_sku></items>

Comment: So I tried what you said Martin and I have it loaded in a simplexml object -- but accessing via <xsl:for-each select="$mi//items"> is not working

Comment: Well, I said DOMDocument and not simplexml, I am not sure whether simplexml works as well. I am currently not set up here to run PHP so I can't help on debugging that approach. I suggest you add the PHP tag to the question and then hopefully someone can help further, consider to edit your question and show exactly what you have as PHP code and then also explain whether "is not working" means you get a certain error or simply no output.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/31342799/252228 for an example to a similar question where a working example is included.